# After Getting Every line from File to Vector, Digits are Changed or Destroyed

Tags: c++

After Getting Every line from File to Vector, Digits are Changed or Destroyed!!
IDK why or how they get destroyed

```
ifstream first_matrix;
first_matrix.open("first.txt");
double temp;
int d;//Dimensions
vector<double> firstv(0);
first_matrix >> d;
//counter should be (d*d) + 1
//cuz we get dimension and here is 2
//and we want get 4 numbers(d*d) and the first line is dimension so (+ 1)
for ( i = 0; i < (d*d) + 1; i++)
{
  first_matrix >> temp;
  firstv.push_back(temp);
}
double** first = new double* [d];
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    first[i] = new double[d]; 
    for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
    {

       //as you can see I want to 
       //put 4numbers of file.txt which is 10, 16, 102, 15
       //into first[i][j]
       first_matrix >> first[i][j];
       std::cout << "Result [" 
                 << i << "] ["
                 << j << "] : "
                 << first[i][j]; 
    }


}
```

but if i delete first_matrix >> temp;
then it's ok
btw its give me -6.27744e+66  for every first[i][j] 
and Yep IK I can Easily Write
I have Something Like This in my "first.txt"

```
2
10
16
102
15
```

so I have a matrix which is 2*2 that gives us 4numbers.
but my problem is getting firt[i][j] from first.txt.
the result should be like this

```
Result[0][0] = 10
Result[0][1] = 16
Result[1][0] = 102
Result[1][1] = 15
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so that others can reproduce your problem. Include the exact input used and the output produced and the output desired.

Comment: Why do you first read the (2*count)+1 vector? It is hard to know what wrong without knowing the format of the file. Please provide an example.

Comment: I don't understand.  In your input loop, you are incrementing `d` but immediately after the loop you overwrite `d` with `count`.  Why increment the `d` variable if you overwrite it after the loop?

Comment: I guess that there is too few data in first.txt if you read the matrix twice.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam Nope I Have Enough Data to Read

Comment: @ThomasMatthews
as you can see in my second code, I write the right answer, that d doesn't matter, the question is why first.txt or getting first.txt is not gonna work?
that d++ is extra,,, d = count is correct.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé
sry.
done

Comment: @pcarter
sry.
done

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: First  your range calculation is wrong and should be `for ( i = 0; i < count * count; ++i)` else you will read 5 elements into the vector but first.txt has only 4. Second where is the data for the second matrix `first` because first.txt contains only one matrix data.

Comment: @Alireza.N This is still not a [mre]. We should be able to copy your code as is into a file, compile and run it. You provided the input file, but what output is expected? If you won't put the time in to do this, why should we take the time to try to help you? It would also be nice if you cleaned up the code so that unnecessary code like the stuff with the `d` variable that Thomas pointed out was removed.

Comment: @pcarter good enough?:\

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks <3

Comment: @TobiasWollgam because we have dimension on the first line so we have count*count +1 numbers in the file

do you this line first_matrix >> d; do smth like counter so after this line we only have 4numbers?
sry for my bad language

Comment: @Alireza.N Your question still had problems. I had to made several edits to get it to compile. See my answer for an example of code that does compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the code I've commented out below. The loop there is reading the numbers from the file. So when the other loops execute, the end of file has been reached so 0 values are returned and stored into `first`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream first_matrix;
first_matrix.open("first.txt");
double temp;
int d;//Dimensions
vector<double> firstv(0);
first_matrix >> d;

// The problem is with the commented code below. It's reading the data from the
// from the file, which keeps the loops below from reading it.
//for ( int i = 0; i < (d*d) + 1; i++)
//  {
//    first_matrix >> temp;
//    firstv.push_back(temp);
//  }
double** first = new double* [d];
for ( int i = 0; i < d; i++)
  {
    first[i] = new double[d];
    for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
      {

        // This was putting zeroes into first[i][j]
        first_matrix >> first[i][j];
        std::cout << "Result ["
                  << i << "] ["
                  << j << "] : "
                  << first[i][j] << std::endl;
      }


  }
}
```

Output of above code:

```
Result [0] [0] : 10
Result [0] [1] : 16
Result [1] [0] : 102
Result [1] [1] : 15
```

Comment: ahhh thank you so much, I was wondering why it's going to empty...